# AngularJs timeout for long response time

Tags: angularjs, time, error-handling, timeout, request

I would create a function which shows a message, if the backend call takes a longer time...

I have tried to wach the $locationChangeSuccess event....

```
        $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newLoc, oldLoc){
           deferred = $timeout(function() {
                    alert('takes more that 10 sec!!!');
                }, 10000);
        });


    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, newLoc, oldLoc){
           console.log('Cancelled: ' + $timeout.cancel(deferred));
        });
```

it didnt works, because the $locationChangeSuccess event fires right after the $location.path(...) (didn't wait the response)

do you know any event which fires right after the response returns?

thanks

Comment: do you want to cancel when it takes a long time or just show a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
app.controller('LocalCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $q) {

    var defer = $q.defer();

    defer.promise.then(function () {
        alert('End request.');
    });

    $timeout(function () {
        defer.resolve();
    }, 2000);

});
```

or use in you routing config:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
            , controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/test', {
              templateUrl: 'views/local.html'
            , controller: 'LocalCtrl'
            , resolve: {
                app: function ($q, $timeout) {
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    $timeout(function () {
                        defer.resolve();
                    }, 2000);

                    return defer.promise;
                }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```